# SignalR which library to use in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular8

I have tried a lot of kind SignalR for Angular. All is not compatible with Angular 8. Some of then are deprecated.

Now in demo test I use library `ASP.NET SignalR JavaScript Library v2.1.2`, it is Jquery file: `jquery.signalR-2.1.2.js`.

What is package of SignalR to use in Anguar 8?

I tried more popular library. `@aspnet/signalr`

It says:

> [2019-09-15T20:51:18.646Z] Error: Failed to start the connection:
>   Error: Detected a connection attempt to an ASP.NET SignalR Server.
>   This client only supports connecting to an ASP.NET Core SignalR
>   Server. See https://aka.ms/signalr-core-differences for details.

Some people said to use `https://www.npmjs.com/package/signalr`, but how to use this package in Angular's components?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a *software library* or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@aspnet/signalr` is the right library for Angular 8 and .NET Core. The error message is clear: your server code is .NET, not .NET Core. I don't think SignalR is supported by .NET. If it *is* - it is quite complex.

So - the issue isn't Angular library; the issue is your server-side framework! You say, it's still demo - so I would suggest to switch to .NET Core. SignalR support is out of the box, easy to implement, and constantly improving